# Showing Variant of Exponential Martingale is a super-martingale

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Let $B_t$ be a standard Brownian motion, and let $a_t$ be progressively measurable and so that $a_t \in [0,1]$ almost surely. It's well known that $e^{\theta B_t - \frac{1}{2} \theta^2 t}$ is a martingale for constants $\alpha.$

Let $M_t = a_t B_t$. I want to show now that $e^{\theta M_t - \frac{1}{2} \theta^2 t}$ is a super-martingale. Intuitively, this should be true because $a_t \in [0,1]$, and the function $e^x$ is convex, so the large positive fluctuations of the Brownian motion are down-weighted. I tried using Ito's lemma to write $$e^{\theta M_t} - 1 = \int_0^t e^{\theta M_s} \theta dM_s + \frac{\theta^2}{2} \int_0^t e^{\theta M_s} a_s^2 ds,$$ though I feel like this is kind of circular, since I don't quite know how to show that this last term is less than $e^{\theta^2t/2}$ (in expectation, which would show that this process is a super-martingale).

Any advice would be great!

Comment: Your notation could benefit greatly from making clear when $\alpha$ is a function of $t.$ Your Ito formula is not circular but wrong.

Answer (score 0):

***First Round***

To have an easier life I will modify slightly your term in the exponential
to be more of a standard form when $\alpha$ is not constant.

From the integration-by-parts formula we get
$$
\theta M_t=\theta\alpha_tB_t=\theta\int_0^t\alpha_s\,dB_s+\theta\int_0^tB_s\,d\alpha_s=:X_t+A_t\,.
$$
From
the Ito formula we get
\begin{align}
e^{\theta M_t-\frac12\langle X\rangle_t}&=1+\int_0^te^{\theta M_s-\frac12\langle X\rangle_s}\,dX_s+\int_0^te^{\alpha_sM_s-\frac12\langle X\rangle_s}\,dA_s
\end{align}
where
$$
\langle X\rangle_t=\theta^2\int_0^t\alpha_s^2\,ds\,.
$$
Since $\int_0^te^{\theta M_s-\frac12\langle X\rangle_s}\,dX_s$ is a martingale it follows from the uniqueness of the Doob-Meyer
decomposition that $e^{\theta M_t-\frac12\langle X\rangle_t}$ is
a supermartingale if and only if
$$
\int_0^te^{\theta M_s-\frac12\langle X\rangle_s}\,dA_s
$$
is decreasing. But this is not the case since
the integrand is
$$
e^{\theta M_s-\frac12\langle X\rangle_s}\,\theta\,\color{red}{B_s}\,\alpha'_s
$$
which is not guaranteed to stay negative.

***Second Round***

If you want instead of $\frac12\langle X\rangle_t$ the compensator $\frac12\theta^2\,t$ we get from the Ito formula

\begin{align}
e^{\theta M_t-\frac12\theta^2t}&=1+\int_0^te^{\theta M_s-\frac12\theta^2s}\,dX_s\\[2mm]
&\quad+\underbrace{\int_0^te^{\alpha_sM_s-\frac12\theta^2s}\,dA_s-\frac12\int_0^te^{\theta M_s-\frac12\theta^2s}\;\theta^2\,ds+\frac12\int_0^te^{\theta M_s-\frac12\theta^2s}\,d\langle X\rangle_s}\,.
\end{align}
The conjecture that $e^{\theta M_t-\frac12\theta^2t}$ is a supermartingale is now equivalent to the underbraced term being decreasing. This is equivalent to the sum of the integrands being negative. That is: to
$$
\theta\,B_s\,\alpha'_s-\theta^2\frac{1-\alpha^2_s}{2}
$$
being negative which is not quaranteed, unless $\alpha$ is constant and in $[0,1]\,.$

Comment: I made some edits; I feel like we are using slightly different notation (in my original question, the $a_t$ and the $\alpha$ are different). Does your solution still hold for the new notation?

Comment: It does. This was the last jump of the old circus horse.